# Интеграция TestRail с Allure Report

Tags: test-automation, allure

Необходим совет знающих. Пытаюсь сделать диаграмму в Allure на основании статусов кейсов TestRail, но не могу найти информацию в интернете. Такая интеграция вообще возможна?